# OS X bash/ZSH - print string + script output

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh

I'm using ZSH & I have a script to get the current uptime in days:

```
uptime | cut -d',' -f1 | sed 's/^.*up *//'
```

But I want to have the text:

```
"       Uptime ---  "
```

In front of the output, so that the total output is

```
"       Uptime --- XX days "
```

I've the following in a separate .sh file and calling this script within the terminal

```
a="       Uptime ---  "
b= uptime | cut -d',' -f1 | sed 's/^.*up *//'

echo $a $b
```

But I get the following output instead:

```
17 days
Uptime ---
```

How can I get them on the same line?

Comment: There's something missing in `b= uptime ...`. Did you mean `b=$(uptime ...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one-liner:

```
echo "       Uptime --- " $(uptime | cut -d',' -f1 | sed 's/^.*up *//')
```

I hope it works as you expect.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.